# Different destination and issuer

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

In the IdP metadata we have a POST binding set to https://www.example.com/Auth95 (all the bindings are set to the same url)

We see the AuthNRequest going with a Destination of https://www.example.com/Auth95

The user logs in successfully and the Response comes back successful but it has an Issuer of https://www.example.com/Auth3 and fails signature validation. Is it SAML-legal to have the Destination and Issuer different and if so how do configure spring-security-saml to ignore the path?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, destination and issuer can differ. Destination is URL of the endpoint where SAML messages get delivered, while Issuer corresponds to entityId of the IDP. Simply change entityId in the IDP metadata you import to Spring SAML to "https://www.example.com/Auth3" and you should be good to go (provided validation actually fails on the Issuer, not on signature as you say).